# Существует ли в русском языке слово "клиентка"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Существует ли в русском языке слово "клиентка"?

Comment: А не проще ли заглянуть в словарь или воспользоваться опцией "Проверка слова" на Грамоте (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)?

Answer (score 5):

Слово "клиентка" существует, так, в Нацкорпусе приведено 127 примеров с этим словом, например: И если покупательница ― постоянная клиентка, мы стоим и молчим.

[клиентка | Национальный корпус русского языка](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EA%EB%E8%E5%ED%F2%EA%E0&p=0)

Но возникает вопрос о  стилевой характеристике слова. Скорее всего, это нейтральный стиль, но не официально-деловой.

У Розенталя: [§148. Род названий лиц женского пола по профессии, должности и т.д.](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_03)

Параллельные названия для обозначения лиц женского пола закрепились в тех случаях, когда данная специальность (профессия, род занятий и т. д.) в равной мере связана и с женским и с мужским трудом, например: акушер – акушерка, буфетчик – буфетчица, лаборант – лаборантка, летчик – летчица, преподаватель – преподавательница, предприниматель – предпринимательница, продавец – продавщица, студент – студентка,  писатель – писательница, спортсмен – спортсменка.

Однако, несмотря на свободное образование подобных названий в форме женского рода, они используются не во всех стилях речи. Так, в официально-деловом стиле предпочтительно сохранять форму мужского рода, когда речь идет о номенклатурном наименовании должности; ср. в документе-справке: «А.В. Петрова работает лаборантом на кафедре физики» (в обиходной речи – лаборантка Петрова).